# Emulator reboots when calling setMyLocationEnabled(true)

Tags: android, android-mapview, genymotion, android-maps-v2, android-googleapiclient

I have an app that displays the users location on a map. It all works fine on API16, 19, 21, 23 and API10 on a *physical Nexus One*, but when I run it on a Genymotion API10 emulator, the emulator reboots when I call

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

*(full sample activity class at the bottom of this post)*

The emulator reboots without any prior notice, and here is the output from the log:

```
    05-26 20:36:02.944 14384-14441/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/LocationManager: locationCallbackFinished: RemoteException
   android.os.DeadObjectException
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
       at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.locationCallbackFinished(ILocationManager.java:763)
       at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:244)
       at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:160)
       at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$2.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:183)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
    05-26 20:36:02.944 14384-14441/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/LocationManager: locationCallbackFinished: RemoteException
   android.os.DeadObjectException
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
       at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.locationCallbackFinished(ILocationManager.java:763)
       at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:244)
       at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:160)
       at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$2.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:183)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
    05-26 20:36:02.944 14384-14441/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/LocationManager: locationCallbackFinished: RemoteException
   android.os.DeadObjectException
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
       at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.locationCallbackFinished(ILocationManager.java:763)
       at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:244)
       at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:160)
       at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$2.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:183)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
    05-26 20:36:02.952 123-123/? E/installd: eof
    05-26 20:36:02.952 123-123/? E/installd: failed to read size
    05-26 20:36:03.092 14223-14223/com.google.process.gapps E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
          java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
              at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ContextImpl.java:1841)
              at odk.b(SourceFile:159)
              at ocv.a(SourceFile:826)
              at ocw.handleMessage(SourceFile:13053)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
           Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
              at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
              at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getApplicationInfo(IPackageManager.java:1264)
              at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ContextImpl.java:1836)
              at odk.b(SourceFile:159) 
              at ocv.a(SourceFile:826) 
              at ocw.handleMessage(SourceFile:13053) 
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) 
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 
              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    05-26 20:36:03.096 14468-14842/com.google.android.gms E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices
    05-26 20:36:03.104 14468-14842/com.google.android.gms E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices
    05-26 20:36:03.104 14468-14842/com.google.android.gms E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices
    05-26 20:36:03.112 14223-14223/? E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
    android.os.DeadObjectException
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:2547)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:76)
        at ilq.uncaughtException(SourceFile:118)
        at ils.uncaughtException(SourceFile:54)
        at ilm.uncaughtException(SourceFile:63)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:854)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:851)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    05-26 20:36:03.128 14468-14842/com.google.android.gms E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices
    05-26 20:36:03.128 14468-14842/com.google.android.gms E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices
    05-26 20:36:03.128 14468-14842/com.google.android.gms E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: SyncAdapterThread-1
        java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadObjectException
            at android.accounts.AccountManager.getAccountsByType(AccountManager.java:394)
            at smx.b(SourceFile:114)
            at tat.a(SourceFile:40)
            at ssg.a(SourceFile:447)
            at ssg.a(SourceFile:189)
            at ssg.a(SourceFile:91)
            at jcj.onPerformSync(SourceFile:98)
            at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:164)
         Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
            at android.accounts.IAccountManager$Stub$Proxy.getAccounts(IAccountManager.java:474)
            at android.accounts.AccountManager.getAccountsByType(AccountManager.java:391)
            at smx.b(SourceFile:114) 
            at tat.a(SourceFile:40) 
            at ssg.a(SourceFile:447) 
            at ssg.a(SourceFile:189) 
            at ssg.a(SourceFile:91) 
            at jcj.onPerformSync(SourceFile:98) 
            at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:164) 
    05-26 20:36:03.128 14468-14842/com.google.android.gms E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
        android.os.DeadObjectException
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:2547)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:76)
            at ilq.uncaughtException(SourceFile:118)
            at ils.uncaughtException(SourceFile:54)
            at ilm.uncaughtException(SourceFile:63)
            at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:854)
            at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:851)
    05-26 20:36:03.472 14873-14947/se.miun.mawi1402.bathingsites E/Surface: Surface (identity=11) requestBuffer(1, 0, 0, 4, 00000200) returned a buffer with a null handle
    05-26 20:36:03.472 14873-14947/se.miun.mawi1402.bathingsites E/Surface: getBufferLocked(1, 0, 0, 4, 00000200) failed (Out of memory)
    05-26 20:36:03.472 14873-14947/se.miun.mawi1402.bathingsites E/EGL_emulation: tid 14947: swapBuffers(322): error 0x3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
    05-26 20:36:03.512 14384-14441/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/LocationManager: removeUpdates: DeadObjectException
   android.os.DeadObjectException
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
       at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.removeUpdates(ILocationManager.java:692)
       at android.location.LocationManager.removeUpdates(LocationManager.java:872)
       at adka.a(SourceFile:79)
       at acpn.b(SourceFile:196)
       at acpk.a(SourceFile:123)
       at acpo.a(SourceFile:133)
       at acpk.a(SourceFile:100)
       at acpv.f(SourceFile:46)
       at acpi.a(SourceFile:62)
       at acpv.f(SourceFile:46)
       at acmw.a(SourceFile:10191)
       at acmq.a(SourceFile:10117)
       at ackx.a(SourceFile:95)
       at acna.a(SourceFile:204)
       at acoz.b(SourceFile:352)
       at acoz.a(SourceFile:235)
       at acof.a(SourceFile:144)
       at acpd.handleMessage(SourceFile:100)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at adkk.dispatchMessage(SourceFile:50)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
    05-26 20:36:03.512 14384-14441/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/LocationManager: RemoteException in unregisterGpsStatusListener: 
   android.os.DeadObjectException
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
       at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.removeGpsStatusListener(ILocationManager.java:746)
       at android.location.LocationManager.removeGpsStatusListener(LocationManager.java:1342)
       at adjw.a(SourceFile:89)
       at acpk.a(SourceFile:7063)
       at acpv.f(SourceFile:46)
       at acpi.a(SourceFile:62)
       at acpv.f(SourceFile:46)
       at acmw.a(SourceFile:10191)
       at acmq.a(SourceFile:10117)
       at ackx.a(SourceFile:95)
       at acna.a(SourceFile:204)
       at acoz.b(SourceFile:352)
       at acoz.a(SourceFile:235)
       at acof.a(SourceFile:144)
       at acpd.handleMessage(SourceFile:100)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at adkk.dispatchMessage(SourceFile:50)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
    05-26 20:36:03.692 14217-14217/com.android.systemui E/InputQueue-JNI: channel 'b6660528 StatusBar (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
    05-26 20:36:03.692 14217-14217/com.android.systemui E/InputQueue-JNI: channel 'b67f7ad0 TrackingView (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
    05-26 20:36:03.692 14217-14217/com.android.systemui E/InputQueue-JNI: channel 'b6949638 StatusBarExpanded (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
    05-26 20:36:03.692 14218-14218/com.android.launcher E/InputQueue-JNI: channel 'b6804400 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
    05-26 20:36:03.744 127-127/? E/local_gps: Can't send RMC command
    05-26 20:36:03.892 14961-14961/? E/ALSALib: external/alsa_lib/src/control/control.c:902:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL AndroidOut
    05-26 20:36:03.892 14961-14961/? E/ALSALib: external/alsa_lib/src/control/control.c:902:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL AndroidIn
    05-26 20:36:03.896 14961-14961/? E/ALSALib: external/alsa_lib/src/pcm/pcm.c:2210:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM AndroidPlayback_Speaker_normal
    05-26 20:36:03.896 14961-14961/? E/ALSALib: external/alsa_lib/src/pcm/pcm.c:2210:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM AndroidPlayback_Speaker
    05-26 20:36:03.896 14961-14961/? E/ALSALib: external/alsa_lib/src/pcm/pcm.c:2210:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM AndroidPlayback
```

Is there any way I can prevent this from happening? I have obviously installed Google Play Services and Google Maps on the emulator, and what's really weird is that the Google Maps app seems to be working fine.

**EDIT**

Full example activity which causes the emulator to reboot:

```
public class MapsActivityExample extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, LocationListener {
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private Location lastLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient, used to deal with device location
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();


        // Create a location request to use when we request location change updates
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000); // 5s
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000); // 1s
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Connect the GoogleApiClient so we can request location updates
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // Disconnect the GoogleApiClient
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }


    // Callback for when the map is ready
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
        mMap = googleMap;
    }


    // Callback for when the GoogleAPIClient is connected
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // Make sure we have permission
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return;

        // Start requesting location updates
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates( mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

        // Enable the MyLocation layer, which displays the device's current location on the map
        if (null != mMap)
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); /** <- THIS SEEMS TO BE WHAT'S CAUSING THE REBOOT **/
    }


    // Callback for when the GoogleAPIClient connection is suspended
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}


    // Callback for when the device location has changed
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Posted a minimal working example for an activity that causes my emulator to reboot.